# iPad: Control for Creating an Image Gallery 

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uiimageview, image-gallery

I want to use an image gallery in an iPad app. There should be multiple thumbnails in the image gallery and when I click one that image will display.

I could not find any control to place the thumbnails.

Usmna Khan 
Iphone Developer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct control available in iPhone SDK. You need to write your own code to make Image Gallery or take the code from other resources. But i will suggest you should try to write your own code.

Cheers,
Raxit

Answer (score 1):

An image gallery is really nothing but a tableview in which each row displays several images side by side. By using a custom cell without borders, you create the illusion of a grid of images.

Answer (score 1):

I have a project on github that can help get you started. It's called KTPhotoBrowser and it does exactly what you describe, displays a grid of thumbnail images and displays the image when tapped. The project is at:

https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser